# Why is my HTTP.call() not working?

Tags: post, meteor, callback, xmlhttprequest

Why isn't my HTTP.call() function working as designed.

When I run the code below in my browser console:

```
var postData = {
data: {

  "username": "SirBT",
  "productName": "Choma",
  "phoneNumber": "+254700087633",
  "currencyCode": "KES",
  "amount": "666"      
  }

}

HTTP.call('POST', ''http://2117c3a8.ngrok.io/AConnect/c2b.php', 
{ headers: { apiKey: 'AC6ea8e1541e7ee0c40915e' }}, 
  postData, 
  function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
} 
);
```

I get this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't make a blocking HTTP call from the client; callback required.(…)
```

After a bit of researching, I found out that I should run it from the server, which I now do but I get these error messages in the terminal:

```
W20170712-17:31:47.726(3)? (STDERR)     /home/sirbt/escrow/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/http.js:187
W20170712-17:31:47.728(3)? (STDERR)       callback(error, response);                                                                                       // 74
W20170712-17:31:47.732(3)? (STDERR)       ^
W20170712-17:31:47.733(3)? (STDERR) 
W20170712-17:31:47.735(3)? (STDERR) TypeError: callback is not a function
W20170712-17:31:47.736(3)? (STDERR)     at     packages/http/httpcall_server.js:74:7
W20170712-17:31:47.737(3)? (STDERR)     at   packages/underscore.js:784:19
W20170712-17:31:47.738(3)? (STDERR)     at Request._callback (packages/http/httpcall_server.js:116:5)
W20170712-17:31:47.740(3)? (STDERR)     at Request.self.callback (/home/sirbt/.meteor/packages/http/.1.2.12.1w7h08f++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)
W20170712-17:31:47.741(3)? (STDERR)     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
W20170712-17:31:47.742(3)? (STDERR)     at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
W20170712-17:31:47.743(3)? (STDERR)     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/sirbt/.meteor/packages/http/.1.2.12.1w7h08f++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1067:10)
W20170712-17:31:47.745(3)? (STDERR)     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
W20170712-17:31:47.746(3)? (STDERR)     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
W20170712-17:31:47.747(3)? (STDERR)     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/sirbt/.meteor/packages/http/.1.2.12.1w7h08f++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:988:12)
=> Exited with code: 1
```

Looking forward to your help

Comment: The answer is reflected in the error message. you should use 'calllback'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 5 arguments while [docs write](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call) you need 4 of them.

Check in my snippet how `postData` field changed, it is in the same object as `headers`

```
HTTP.call('POST', 'http://2117c3a8.ngrok.io/AConnect/c2b.php', { 
  headers: { apiKey: 'AC6ea8e1541e7ee0c40915e' }, 
  data: postData
}, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you! You really saved me hours of agony! Any chance you might be able to help me with this one that derived from the above question:[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065295/how-do-i-modify-my-http-call-so-that-it-returns-relevant-information